# Python Selenium Issue With Meta Open Graph xpath selector

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have confirmed the xpath works using a Google Chrome plugin that tests xpaths.
This is the xpath:

//meta[@property='og:url']/@content

and this is the line of code that works with other xpaths so I know the only variable is this current xpath:

```
pageID = get_data(driver,"//meta[@property='og:url']/@content")
```

But when I run my Python Selenium script I get the error:

"invalid selector" "it should be an element."

**Am I only allowed to use xpaths that are visible? How can I select hidden elements that require view-page source?**

*NOTE: Thank you and my apologies if I am missing any information. This is my first post here and I only created a profile because I searched everywhere online and couldn't find a solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the question how the method `get_data()` is defined.

However, to extract the *pageID* you can use `find_element_by_xpath()` along with [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method as follows:

```
pageID = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//meta[@property='og:url']").get_attribute("content")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!
I just tried that but got this mesage:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' `

Will keep experimenting and googling about this issue.